# 401 Error when interacting with Restful Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, http

I'm pretty new to HTTP requests and RESTful APIs in general. I'm currently interacting with a service through an ASP.Net application. The services I'm using require encrypted authorization to access their POST, PUT and DELETE methods.

I'm fairly certain I've obtained the authorization correctly according to the manual I was provided. H. I'm currently on testing the Delete method. When I delete an entry on my web page, I am met with the "401 Unauthorized error". Visual studio tells me the status of the 401 error is "ProtocolError". Have I done something wrong with my authorization? Am I not including a header that I need to? Do I need to edit my web.config file? I'm running the site on my local machine. Any help or advice is much appreciated. Thank you.

**Here are the methods I'm using to get my authorization:**

```
public static string HMACSHA1(string key, string dataToSign)
  {
     Byte[] secretBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
     HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(secretBytes);

     Byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSign);
     Byte[] calcHash = hmac.ComputeHash(dataBytes);
     String calcHashString = Convert.ToBase64String(calcHash);
     return calcHashString;

  }

  public string get_auth(string HTTP_METHOD, string uri)
  {
     string auth = "EWS" + " " + Access_ID() + ":" + get_signature(HTTP_METHOD, uri);
     return auth;
  }
  public string get_signature(string HTTP_METHOD, string resource)
  {
     string userpass = "userpass";
     string StringToSign = get_string_to_sign(HTTP_METHOD, get_resource());
     string signature = string.Empty;
     return HMACSHA1(userpass, StringToSign);
  }
  public string Access_ID()
  {
     string Access_ID = string.Empty;
     string username = "username";
     string userName = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username));
     return userName; 

  }
  public string get_string_to_sign(string HTTP_METHOD,string resource)
  {

     string string_to_sign = string.Empty;
     string_to_sign = HTTP_METHOD + "\n" + DateTime.Now.ToString("r")  +"\n"+  resource;
     return string_to_sign; 
  }
```

**Here is my delete method:**

```
public void Delete(string destination_url)
  {

     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destination_url);
     request.Method = "DELETE";
     request.Headers["x-zws-date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("r");
     string auth = get_auth(request.Method, destination_url);
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
     request.KeepAlive = true;
     request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
     request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

     HttpWebResponse response;

     response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     try
     {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
           Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
           string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        }
     }
     catch (WebException ex)
     {

        if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
           HttpWebResponse responsed = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;

           var statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
           Response.Write("An error occurred, status code: " + statusCode);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
        Response.Write(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
     }
  }
```

**Delete example from the documentation:**

```
HTTP method 
DELETE 
Authorization: Yes 
Variable: None 
Status code 
200 OK Successful 
400 Bad Request Data does not match with ID or this type does not exist. 
401 Unauthorized User name or password is wrong or the authority of a user 
to access to this data processing has not been obtained. 
404 Not Found Data record not found. 
405 Method Not Allowed The data record could not be deleted since there is 
physical sample corresponding to this record. 

Example 
http://localhost//webservicename/Tool/4444 
DELETE http://localhost/webservicename/Tool/4444 HTTP/1.1 Authorization: ZWS 
dXNlcg==:dXNlcg== User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1 Host: localhost 
Date: Thu, 10 Jun 2010 10:42:52 GMT 
Reply 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Length: 0 Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/1.0 Date: Thu, 
10 Jun 2010 10:42:52 GMT
```

Comment: Third party rest api?...do you have access to their documentation for their `delete` method?

Comment: just updated my question.

Comment: Does the api documentation specify `request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;` ?

Comment: No. Unfortunately there is nothing in the manual about Protocol Version. I've tried both version 10 and 11 with no avail. The manual is not written for C# in particular.

Comment: Are other methods working that require authorization?

Comment: No. No other methods that require authorization are currently working.

Comment: Is ssl required? Did you test with https?

Comment: No. SSL is not required.

Comment: Have you tried calling the API using Postman or Fiddler?

Comment: I have fiddler installed. Not completely sure how to call the API using it though.